# Testing disabled button reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing

I have a React export button component which will be disabled when `totalRecords` exceed ORDER_LIMIT or equal 0. The code looks like below:

```
interface ExportExcelButtonProps {
  filterValues: OrderFilter;
  totalOrders: number;
}

const ExportExcelButton: React.FC<ExportExcelButtonProps> = ({ filterValues, totalOrders }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const disabled = totalOrders === 0 || totalOrders > ORDER_LIMIT;
  
  const onExportBtnClick = async () => {
    ...
  };

  return (
   <Button
      disabled={disabled}
      loading={loading}
      onClick={onExportBtnClick}
      type="primary"
      icon={<DownloadOutlined />}
      data-testid="export-btn"
    >
      {t("ExportExcel")}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Code in the parent components:

```
    const { orders, filters, pagination } = useOrderData(); // Fetch order data from this hook
    const totalOrders = pagination.total || 0;
    ....
    <ExportExcelButton filterValues={filters} totalOrders={totalOrders} />
```

I'm trying to test my ExportExcelButton by a test case like this:

```
   it("exports by orderDate", async () => {
    const dummyDateRange = [dayjs("2020-10-20T00:00:00+07:00"), dayjs("2020-10-30T23:59:59+07:00")];
    fireEvent.change(orderDateField, { target: { value: "1", payload: dummyDateRange } });

    userEvent.click(searchButton);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(getOrdersMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(exportButton).toBeEnabled();
    });

    userEvent.click(exportButton);
    await waitFor(() => {
      const params = {
        startDate: dummyDateRange[0].format(),
        endDate: dummyDateRange[1].format(),
        limit: ORDER_LIMIT,
      };
      expect(exportOrdersMock).toBeCalledWith(expect.objectContaining(params));
    });
  });
```

When i run the test file, test case above failed because export button still be disabled

```
  expect(element).toBeEnabled()
    Received element is not enabled:
      <button class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary" data-testid="export-btn" disabled="" style="pointer-events: none;" type="button" />
```

But when I check in snapshot file, this button does not have `disabled` attribute:

```
 <button
   class="ant-btn ant-btn-primary"
   data-testid="export-btn"
   type="button"
 >
```

I already mock data with `totalOrders = 1` in `getOrdersMock`. I think component `ExportExcelButton` didn't update when `totalOrders` changed during testing. How can I make `ExportExcelButton` update? Any other ways to test this case?

Comment: What is ORDER_LIMIT?
Try to `console.log(disabled, totalOrders)`, what does it log?

Comment: I set ORDER_LIMIT = 500, when I log `console.log(disabled, totalOrders)`, firstly, it logged 'true 0' , in the end it logged 'false 1'

Comment: Maybe you should create a codesandbox

Comment: sorry I cannot provide a codesandbox because of big code base, by the way, I found the solution by getting `exportButton`  from snapshot right before the line `expect(exportButton).toBeEnabled()`. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
  getOrdersMock = jest.spyOn(orderApis, "getOrdersList");
  exportOrdersMock = jest.spyOn(orderApis, "exportOrders");

  ({ container } = render(
    <Router>
      <OrderList />
    </Router>
  ));

  exportButton = screen.getByTestId("export-btn") as HTMLButtonElement;
});
```

`exportButton` which I defined in `beforeEach` only capture snapshot in the very first rendering, after click `searchButton`, the snapshot will be updated. Therefore, I have to get my `exportButton` from snapshot again.

```
    userEvent.click(searchButton);
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(getOrdersMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

    exportButton = screen.getByTestId("export-btn") as HTMLButtonElement; // add this line
    
    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(exportButton).toBeEnabled();
    });
```